# What does this logcat line means?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, logcat

My app runs as expected, except when I select the last option on my Navigation Drawer.  Then I get the error

```
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2062 SIG: 9
```

... and then the app crashes.
Help?

When i use this code , it when the crash happen:

```
 BindDictionary<ListaRecompensas> dictionary = new BindDictionary<>();
    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.lrnivel, new StringExtractor<ListaRecompensas>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(ListaRecompensas listaRecompensas, int position) {
            return listaRecompensas.getName();
        }
    });
    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.lrqty, new StringExtractor<ListaRecompensas>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(ListaRecompensas listaRecompensas, int position) {
            return "" + listaRecompensas.getQty();
        }
    });

    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.lrexp, new StringExtractor<ListaRecompensas>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(ListaRecompensas listaRecompensas, int position) {
            return "" + listaRecompensas.getExp();
        }
    });

    FunDapter adapter = new FunDapter(Recompensas.this.getActivity(),lrecompensas, R.layout.lrecompensas, dictionary);

    ListView lv01 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv01);
    lv01.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This looks like a classic Linux OS kill command that will terminate the process. Your App in this case.

Comment: yeah, i dont know how to fix that.. can you help me ?

Comment: There will be a java stacktrace associated with your app crashing. Please post this and any code which is called prior to the crash.

Comment: i put the fragment code it gave me that error, i only fix that removing this part of code

Comment: Please post the java stacktrace also

Comment: That is not the crash log.